# Angularjs Scope not working with selectboxit plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selectboxit

I am using selectboxit plugin for the selection list on my angularJS page an have bind the "ng-change" event on it. But unfortunately, it is not giving me the data on change.

index.html

```
    <select data-ng-model="object.word" ng-change="test(object.word)" id="blog-cat">
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>

                                <option ng-hide="item.name == ''" ng-repeat="item in businessParentItems track by $index" value="{{item.term_id}}" item-business-directive>{{item.name}}</option>
                            </select>
{{object.word}}
```

testCtrl.js

```
$scope.test = function(test) {
        console.log('got it!');
}
```

directive.js

```
resource_app.directive('itemBusinessDirective', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last === true) {
                $('.resources-search-bar .container .select-part select').selectBoxIt();

        }
    };
});
```

Please help with this to render the ng-model value on change of selection list.

Comment: change function not working?

Comment: Yes, on change i have console logged some value as well as printed the modal value `{{object.word}}`. But it is not working.

Comment: got it! from console not working?

Comment: Yes from console as well as from expression both not working. Angularjs not understanding `ng-model`. Don't know why.

Comment: did you mentioned ng-controller in code?

Comment: change data-ng-model to only ng-model.

Comment: Tried in both was as `object.word` and `word`.

Comment: Yes those also did. But same not worked.

Comment: Can you share your full code? with ng-app and ng-controller mentioned

Comment: According to you what should be the cause of this issue.? Actually, the code is huge so that's why sharing would be very difficult here.

Comment: Issue may be your controller is not working, or you not placed the ng-app and ng-controller directive in correct place.

Comment: I am using this `http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/?buffer_share=d9cb8` library to render selection list. All are working except scope rendering. Also tried with `scope.$apply()` inside directive after `$last`. But same issue.

Comment: I have included the ng-app and ng-controller after body container. It has scope throughout the page. Have tested it with console log.